# Is it possible, to create custom view in UICollectionViewListCell using XIB?

Tags: ios, swift

All the while, I am using XIB to create custom view in `UICollectionViewCell`.

Recently, I need to support the following features in `UICollectionView`

- editing mode, which will display reorder and delete button
- swipe to delete

It seems like using `UICollectionViewListCell` is the way to go, because it has properties `accessories`.

I do not find much information, on how to create custom view in `UICollectionViewListCell` (For instance, I need to place a `UIButton` and a `UITextView` in it)

The only information I have found, is using `UIHostingConfiguration` and SwiftUI.

https://swiftsenpai.com/development/swiftui-custom-cell/

However, at the moment, we are not ready to use SwiftUI.

Is it ever possible, to create custom view in `UICollectionViewListCell` using XIB?

Comment: Why not use table view in your case ?

Comment: You should be able to just make your custom cell class inherit from UICollectionViewListCell and ensure that you add any UI elements to the `contentView` in interface builder

Comment: I think you can design Custom **UICollectionViewListCell in Interface Builder**. You can check out more details from https://swiftsenpai.com/development/custom-uicollectionviewlistcell-in-ib/